# How to convert concatenated defines into a string in an RC file?

Tags: c++

I have an RC file with these defines inside:

```
#define V_MAJOR 0
#define V_MINOR 0
#define V_PATCH 0
#define V_BUILD 2
#define DOT .

#define V_STRING V_MAJOR##DOT##V_MINOR##DOT##V_PATCH##DOT##V_BUILD
```

How do I turn V_STRING into a literal string?

I tried the following code (which I found on the internet and supposedly works)

```
#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)
```

and then I called STRINGIZE on V_STRING, but instead of turning the values into strings, it turned the identifiers into strings. (AKA it displays "V_MAJORDOTV_MINORDOTV_PATCHDOTV_BUILD" in the properties tab in explorer for the Product Version.)

I basically want V_STRING to return "0.0.0.2", using V_MAJOR, V_MINOR, V_PATCH and V_BUILD. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, redefine your version numbers as given below.

```
#define V_MAJOR "0"
#define V_MINOR "0"
#define V_PATCH "0"
#define V_BUILD "2"
#define DOT "."
```

Please note that the version numbers are inside double quotes.

Then redefine VS_STRING as given below.

```
    #define V_STRING V_MAJOR DOT V_MINOR DOT V_PATCH DOT V_BUILD
```

Note that NO token paste operator is used.

Now you can use the VS_STRING macro inside an RC file as given below.

```
// Other stuffs
VALUE "FileVersion", V_STRING
// Other stuffs
```

Also, you can use the VS_STRING macro in code as given below.

```
    char* ptszVersion = V_STRING;
    printf( "Version number is %s", ptszVersion );
```

See below output.

Version number is 0.0.0.2

Comment: Thanks, although now on the properties tab in explorer, the "File Version" is set to 0.0.0.0 while the "Product Version" is getting the correct number. Do you know why this would be happening?

Comment: I figured it out:

`#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x
    #define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)

    #define V_MAJOR 0
    #define V_MINOR 0
    #define V_PATCH 0
    #define V_BUILD 2
    #define DOT "."

    #define S_MAJOR STRINGIZE(V_MAJOR)
    #define S_MINOR STRINGIZE(V_MINOR)
    #define S_PATCH STRINGIZE(V_PATCH)
    #define S_BUILD STRINGIZE(V_BUILD)

    #define V_STRING S_MAJOR DOT S_MINOR DOT S_PATCH DOT S_BUILD`

because apparently the "File Version" is taken from the FILEVERSION statement, which requires integers, while the "Product Version" is taken from VALUE "ProductVersion", a string.